# What's this kind of bash syntax?

Tags: bash

```
CFLAGS="-g -O0" ./configure
```

How's `CFLAGS="-g -O0"` picked up in `configure`?

Anyone knows this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, you're setting CFLAGS as an environment variable to be passed into ./configure. You can set any number of environment variables this way if you happen to need more than one.

Comment: You could do CFLAGS="-g -O0" SOMETHING_ELSE="hello" A_THIRD_THING="hello again" ./configure

Answer (score 0):

-g: 
C compilation options which relate to optimization or debugging (usually just -g or -O).  Usually this wouldn't include -I options to specify the include directories, because then you
 couldn't override it on the command line easily as in the above example.

For more information, you can refer this url.

http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html